# Quartile measure on SO profiles

Tags: discussion, feature-request

With the addition of careers and SO being used on CV's etc, it might be an idea to add a few things to a user's profile:

- Quartile: e.g. *foo is in the top 4% of SO users*

This could actually be extended (maybe extra features unlocked either by reputation or possibly by payment) so that more analysis can be done:

- *foo is in the top 10% of responders in the C# tag*
- *75% of bar's questions have been tagged plzsendtehcodez*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at what [Ohloh.net](http://ohloh.net) does; I think they've setup a decent ranking system with nice visuals.  Of course, given that they currently rank [me](http://www.ohloh.net/people/rankings?show=5035) just above [Andrew Morton](http://www.ohloh.net/people/rankings?show=13492639771236), I must admit they *might* have some issues with the ranking itself.

Answer (score 0):

The top responders thing can be seen in the tag stats. The other stat can be simply queried from StackQL. I don't see much use for it personally.

Comment: It's true that you can see this stuff in the tag stats - I think that more detailed and available stats for non-programming SO users (i.e. recruitment consultants, prospective employers etc) is still a good idea